# Adding Footer for GridButtonColumn

Tags: asp.net, footer, telerik-grid

I'm using a Radgrid and I want to put the sum of a GridButtonColumn cells in the footer, is there any way to do this ?

Comment: You want to sum buttons ? Please clarify, is there something in button text that you want to sum or something else

Comment: I want to sum the values of the buttons, there is integer values in the buttons and I want to add the total to the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OnCustomAggregate grid event and sum your values there, here is a KB article about summing :

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-totals-in-footers.html

and example of usage :

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/aggregates/defaultcs.aspx

look at the code behind, method RadGrid1_CustomAggregate, this is a custom sum for boolean column "Discontinued" from that example.

Comment: Aggregate property doesn't come with the GridButtonColumn

Comment: yes, your request is pretty unusal one. Can you add another GridNumericColumn and fill it with the same data as button and sum that one

Comment: I can't add two columns with the same values, the users will get confused

Comment: Well I would surly be confused if you sum my buttons :) What happens if you click on one of that buttons ?

Comment: they don't look like typical buttons, they look like links. When a button clicked a schedule contains detailed information appears

Comment: I'm feeling a bit lost here. I can't find the method RadGrid1_CustomAggregate in the code behind in the example of usage. (I'm actually having a hard time finding an example on how to implement a method like RadGrid1_CustomAggregate anywhere in the internet.)

Comment: Yes, Telerik changed that page, sorry I am not using this anymore but I found an example here : https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-footer-with-multiple-columns-with-custom-aggregate, hope it helps